# getting same type of inherited class items from base class list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Animal {   }

class Tiger : Animal {    }

class Lion : Animal {    }
```

Adding some animals(lions and tigers derived from parent `Animal` class) to the list of animals.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
        animals.Add(new Tiger());
        animals.Add(new Tiger());
        animals.Add(new Tiger());
        animals.Add(new Lion());
        animals.Add(new Lion());
        animals.Add(new Lion());

        List<Tiger> tigers = new List<Tiger>();

        foreach (var item in animals){
            if(item is Tiger){
                var _tiger = item as Tiger;
                tigers.Add(_tiger);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would get the list of tigers using the above foreach loop, but is there any implementation to get the list if tigers using Linq,

like `List<Tiger> tigers = animals.where(somePredicate)` ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
List<Tiger> tigers = animals.OfType<Tiger>().ToList();
```

Comment: This won't compile without adding `ToList` at the end.

Comment: @Lee but in most cases you just need IEnumerable<Tiger>, not List<Tiger>, so it's easier to declare the variable with `var`

Answer (score 1):

var tigers = animals.Where(a => a is Tiger);

Comment: Thanks. but it gives me a return type of `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<ConsoleApplication1.Animal>` instead of `List<Tigers>`.

Comment: A change to @3dd answer,
try this
`List<Tiger> tigers = animals.Where(a => a is Tiger).ToList();`

Comment: @Sid it doesn't compile: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApplication1.Animal>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApplication1.Tiger>`

Comment: My bad forgot to add `animal` class. try this
`List<Tiger> tigers = animals.Where(a => a is Tiger).ToList<Animal>();`

Comment: Check OfType source at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#d25cf953c577dcd6#references. It's `if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;`. SO you can write `animals.Where(a => a is Tiger).Select(a => (Tiger)a).ToList();` or `animals.Where(a => a is Tiger).Cast<Tiger>().ToList();`. But `OfType` solves them all.

Comment: @Sid we will not able to convert a `List<Animal>` to `List<Tiger>`. You are trying to do the same, which is not possible.

Comment: `List<Tiger> tigers = animals.Where(a => a is Tiger).ToList<Tiger>();`